# How to add SPF value for domain on godaddy

Tags: spf

I have my domain hosted on godaddy and i am using their host as mail server ie smtpout.secureserver.net. I need to add SPF settings for my domain. I tired different options but none of them working. Below are the options i tried:

Type: txt
Name: @
Value: v=spf1 mx -all

Type: txt
Name: @
Value: "v=spf1 ip4:SERVER_IP_FROM_WHERE_EMAILS_ARE_SEND -all"

Type: txt
Name: @
Value: v=spf1 ip4:SERVER_IP_FROM_WHERE_EMAILS_ARE_SEND -all

Please confirm what value should i use and how can i confirm whether my settings are correct. Right now, i am checking by sending email from the domain and then checking the mail header which says "spf=fail"

Comment: The headers will tell you what IP or domain failed - that's what you need to add to your SPF.

Comment: I don't see any IP in the header, i added ip of server from where i am sending emails. And should txt value in double quotes or without double quotes ?

Comment: The quotes are not usually part of the record - whether you need them is up to your particular DNS provider. Please post the headers you receive - it is very unusual for an SPF failure to not provide that information.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I added this as txt value v=spf1 include:secureserver.net -all and it is showing spf = pass for most of the emails i send from that domain. But few emails shows spf = fail. What i can be doing wrong, It should either be pass or fail for all emails. Or there is some restriction on spf and so for some emails it passes and for some it fails.

Comment: If you don’t show us the headers, we can’t tell.

Comment: @Wasimaalli Is the SPF record passing the 10 dns queries limit when you check it on SPF survey (do a web search for that tool) or other SPF validation tool?

Comment: @Wasimaalli I ask because _includes_ often have a lot of DNS overhead and if you have an MX (unnecessary) in the SPF that makes it do another round of DNS queries.